# Menu Responsive in Bootstrap 3.x

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used Bootstrap 3.3.7 in my web design. It's working fine with Mobile, Desktop or Laptop. But for a tablet, I can't see three bar menu. If we take bootstrap default navbar,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

It doesn't work for a tablet device. This is not only mine, you can see in [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/). When you browse on a tablet, you will notice that. Is it intentionally left or else something.

I would be very much thankful for your suggestion. I guess it will help for other who get such issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If you mark my answer as accepted, I would be happy, @Humbal.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some CSS rules if you want to see three bar menu on tablets. Bootstrap shows that menu for `<768px`.

```
@media (max-width: 1023px) {  //1024 px for laptop
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
       display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gurkan for your suggestion.  When I implemented this code, I can see the three bar menu. But as soon as I click on the bar, the menu opens and automatically closes. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Humbal I added css  `.collapse.in` in answer. try it please.